# Is it possible to "Praise" a user from a WorkFlow generated Yammer message?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, office-365, yammer

There are two content types associated with the list I'm working on: `{Target, Complete}`. I have a workflow that converts a list item from a `Target` to a `Complete`.

It was requested that this results in **a Yammer post that also "Praises" the target user**, but I cannot find a way to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm looking for any possible way to accomplish this.

Comment: @RobertLindgren My apologies. Is this wording better? I'm new to this SE and did not realize third-party products were taboo here.

Comment: Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chhopkin/archive/2014/02/24/getting-praises-from-your-yammer-network.aspx.

Comment: Sure, my pleasure. Actually, it was about finding "praise" messages, but the JSON diagram was very informative for me some time ago. Please see other links in my answer down there, and feel free to comment - I'd love to refresh my Yammer skills while helping you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by calling https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json REST endpoint. Nintex Workflow and SharePoint Designer workflows both have activities to make REST calls.

[Endpoint documentation is here](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messages-json-post). It also includes interactive "try it" feature.

Also, [this thread at O365 forums](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/176/t/410804) has a sample of valid JSON, but I did not test it.

Comment: Wow, those endpoint docs are crucial. Thanks for the heads up on that!  Not enough rep to +1 your answer, but I've accepted it.